# select one random number from each row of a 2D list in python3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a project, I have a list like this:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

I want to select one number from each row, and that is the index for column of that row. Example: if we select 0 from 1st, 2 from 2nd, 0 from 3rd, 1 from 4th row, then output as follows

```
[['1', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '1', '0', '0']]

1 0 0 0  
0 0 1 0  
1 0 0 0  
0 1 0 0
```

my work is as follows

```
for i in range(0,len(a)): 
    print(random.choice(a))
```

but it prints one of the sub lists.

Comment: Yes, `random.choice(a)` will pick a sub-list. Did you mean `for sublist in a: print(random.choice(sublist))`?

Comment: yes, for each sub list one random number

Comment: Or even `random.choice(a[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2]]  
for x in a:
    b=[0,0,0,0]
    if x:
        b[x.index(random.choice(x))]=1
        print b
    else:print b
```

Comment: why error for a = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], []]   how to  handle...I am new to python

Comment: In this case index will be out of range error you will get as last sublist is empty. so if your list have empty sublist you need to check it via condition

Comment: a = [[], [1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2]] for this, i want same result like random number from 2,3,4th rows first row should be all 0s

Comment: yes the 1st sublist is empty, so you will get same error.

Comment: can u tell me what is that condition...?